# Black Fragment after Transaction

Tags: android

I have a FragmentActivity with a TabMenu. My menu opens a DialogFragment that subsequently call a method that refresh the first fragment in the TabMenu, but when I called this method the second Fragment (Second Section Tab) will become Blank. I can't understand why.

This is the Fragment with its refresh method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_company, container, false);

    ......

    observer = new HomeCompanyFragmentController(this, this.getActivity().getBaseContext());


    return rootView;
}


public void refresh(){
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment newFragment = this;
    this.onDestroy();
    ft.remove(this);
    ft.replace(R.id.pager,newFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

}
```

I followed this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Here I return my fragment:

```
 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:

                if(homeFragment == null){
                    homeFragment = new HomeCompanyFragment();
                }

                return homeFragment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is what's causing your problem, but you should definitely not be performing fragment transactions from the fragment you are trying to remove.  This action should be handled by the activity hosting these fragments, and should be called using the "listener" pattern.  Try putting that logic into the activity and see if it helps.

This link jumps to the part about communicating with the activity, but the whole thing is worth a read.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity